# How to partially load entity framework POCO

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an EF 4.0 model that has a parent child relationship (say order and orderdetails)

order
{
   [primative]
   orderid,
   ordername,
   ordershipping

[navigation]
   orderdetails
}

orderdetail
{
   orderdetailid,
   orderpartid,
   orderquantity,
   orderpartname
}

My question is how do i load orders with orderdetails where the quantity is greater than 1 in LINQ?

for example

var orders = (from o in context.Orders.Include("OrderDetails")
              where....

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay simple answer actually...

http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2009/10/07/ef-include-with-where-clause.aspx